# Simple Apache Server Module

Tags: c, apache, apache2

I created a simple Apache server module following a sample hello world module I found somewhere. Then I added a variable that would track the number of visits on my page. Here is my module code:

```
/* The simplest HelloWorld module */
#include <httpd.h>
#include <http_protocol.h>
#include <http_config.h>

static int noOfViews = 0;

static int helloworld_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    noOfViews++;

    if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "helloworld")) {
        return DECLINED;
    }

    if (r->method_number != M_GET) {
        return HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;
    }

    ap_set_content_type(r, "text/html;charset=ascii");
    ap_rputs("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\">\n",
             r);
    ap_rputs("<html><head><title>Apache HelloWorld "
             "Module</title></head>", r);
    ap_rputs("<body><h1>Hello World!</h1>", r);
    ap_rputs("<p>This is the Apache HelloWorld module!</p>", r);
    ap_rprintf(r, "<p>Views: %d</p>", noOfViews);
    ap_rputs("</body></html>", r);
    return OK;
}

static void helloworld_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{
    ap_hook_handler(helloworld_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA helloworld_module = {
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
            helloworld_hooks
};
```

My module is currently experiencing 2 problems that I am unable to figure out.

1. My views count seems to go up in multiples of 2 even though I only want it to increment 1 at a time.
2. When I constantly refresh my page, sometimes my number randomly falls.

Does anyone know what the sources of my problems could be?

Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're incrementing your counter for requests that you don't actually handle.
2. Each worker process in Apache has its own copy of `noOfViews`. This applies whether you're using the prefork or worker MPM; it's just more a pronounced issue with prefork.